# Private Photos on Surface Pro

Tags: windows-8, privacy, microsoft-surface

So when you take a picture with surface pro it adds it to the livetile slideshow, which I think I can disable all together (but not per photo), and I think my photos are automatically shared by default, which I'm sure I can turn off.

My question is, is there way to tell my surface "Hey I'm gonna take a photo I want it saved to this folder, not shared, and don't put it in my livetile for everyone to see. " But still have normal pictures I take be shared and in the livetile slideshow?

I like the slideshow its a neat little flair and it will bring up photos I forgot I took and can be fun, and I like having access across devices to my photos, but there are some photos I take that I want to keep hidden (no not nudes just things like whiteboard snapshots from work and I'm considering a photo-a-day project I would like to keep private).

Do I have any options that aren't all or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the pictures in a folder and "Hide" the folder (right click > properties > "hidden"), they won't show up in the live-tile.

Update. A better solution is to go to the file or the folder > Properties > Advanced Properties > And De-select "Allow This File To Have It's Contents Indexed"

Then you need to "rebuild the search index" see [here](http://macgateway.com/windows/windows-8-rebuild-search-index/)

Comment: this works if i refresh the live tile, but it still pushes any new picture i take to the live tile, if i move the image to the hidden folder, it still appears in the live tile until i force a refresh. I wish I could tell it to take the picture in the hidden folder instead of camera roll, but then still have the camera roll be the default if i take another picture later.

For now my solution is to use a different app (onenote right now) to take he pictures I don't want in the photo gallery.